# Styling Linkify

Tags: android, linkify

Is there any way to style the links produced by a Linkify.addLinks() operation? Specifically I want to change from the default blue color.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that styling linkify is possible, but if you want to add links , you might want to use a webview with transparent background so that you can use html text on it. I tried searching for linkify styling and couldnt find anything, so i used webview and made the background transparent which is a lot more easier and can do a lot more than just links and styling. Good luck :)

Comment: Even before you answered I'd gone for a WebView :) . I also could not find any reference to styling Linkify.